# How to waiting for the Alert Form to close Then show another alert form c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, popup, alert, wait

I want to show lot of alert straight not all at once

```
     for (int i = 0; i < dc.person.Count(); i++)
           {
               personActuel = dc.person.Skip(i).Take(1).First();

               if (paid.Find(c => c.nume == personActuel.numE) == null)
               {
                   this.Alert("msg" + " " + personActuel.nom + " " + personActuel.prenom + " date :", CulcPay(personActuel.dateAff.Value));

                  // Thread.Sleep(6000);


               }
           }
```

I used

> Thread.Sleep(6000);

but I don't want the **system** to wait , I just want **Form_Alert** to wait

Comment: What is `Alert`? Form? If Form - I didn't see where you call `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: **thank you** .. i used  `ShowSialog()` with `Timer` to close it automatically